# XRegExp for email address

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, xregexp

I want to write regular expression for email address for all including non-italic characters.

I tried but it return false

Please provide correct solution as soon as possible

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.1.1/xregexp-all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var em = XRegExp('^([\\p{L}+|\\p{N}*][@][\\p{L}+][.][\\p{L}+])$'); // Please help me to correct it
 jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('input').blur(function(){
   console.log(jQuery(this).val());
   console.log(em.test(jQuery('#t1').val()));
   
  });
 });
 
</script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Enter Name: <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" class="kcd">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _non-italic characters_?

Comment: `<input type="email" />`

Comment: Maybe non-Italian letters? The regex is clearly messed up due to the wrong use of character classes. Must be something like `XRegExp('^[\\p{L}\\p{N}]+@\\p{L}+[.]\\p{L}+$')`

Comment: Question has nothing to do with jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are better means to make sure your email regex is valid (see [@Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286442/xregexp-for-email-address/39286600#comment65906914_39286442)), I'd like to explain what the problem is with your regex.

The `^([\\p{L}+|\\p{N}*][@][\\p{L}+][.][\\p{L}+])$` contains incorrectly formed character classes `[\\p{L}+|\\p{N}*]` and `[\\p{L}+]`. They match a single character defined inside them - `[\\p{L}+|\\p{N}*]` matches either a `p`, `{`, `L`, etc. and `[\\p{L}+]` matches either a `p`, `{`, `L`, `}`,  or `+`.

If you plan to use your approach, you might want to fix the regex as

```
XRegExp('^[\\p{L}\\p{N}]+@\\p{L}+[.]\\p{L}+$')
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[\\p{L}\\p{N}]+`  - one or more Unicode letters or digits
- `@` - "at" sign
- `\\p{L}+` - one or more Unicode letters
- `[.]` -  a literal dot
- `\\p{L}+` - ibid.
- `$` - end of string.